# Density of current in a Elementary Dipole

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, density, dipole, dipole-moment

I can't understand this formula from my textbook, I'm trying to understand why the Density of Current is I*ΔZ(ΔZ is the lenght of the dipole) i mean a density of current would be I/Δs (with Δs the section of the cable, that is almost 0 since we have an elementary dipole):
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way a current element shows up in radiation is via the formula for the vector potential $\mathbf A$ and $\mu_0 \mathbf H = \nabla \times \mathbf A$, as function of the radiating current density $\mathbf J$:
$$\mathbf {A(r)} = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \int \frac{1}{|\mathbf {r-r'}|}\mathbf {J}\left(t-\tfrac{|\mathbf {r-r'}|}{c}\right)dV' \tag{1}$$
The current passing through an area $ds$ is $\mathbf J ds$ and if a linear current element is along an infinitesimal vector $\vec{d\ell}$ and is confined to an infinitesimal volume $dV= ds d\ell$ then $\mathbf J ds d\ell = I d\vec{\ell}$. Considering that the current is infinitesimal and is confined to be around the origin $\mathbf r'=0$, this results in
$$\mathbf {A(r)} 
=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \frac{1}{|\mathbf {r}|}I\left(t-\tfrac{|\mathbf {r}|}{c}\right)\vec{d\ell} \tag{2}$$
In Eq. (2) $I(t)\vec{d\ell} = \mathbf {\dot p(t)}$ is the radiating dipole moment whose time variation is explicitly indicated and, for example, it could be sinusoidal, $\mathbf {p}(t)=\mathbf {\hat p} cos(\omega_0 t)$. One could say that $I$ is the linear *density* of the dipole moment, or more precisely, the latter's time rate but I have never heard that being referred to this way until now...